# Unable to get columns that are selected in Join query in PHP Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I am using Phalcon PHP framework. I am new to this. I tried the below approach to join tables and select columns from those tables. But, it only returns data from the main table only.

```
$jumpstarts = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
        ->columns("products.title, users_jumpstart.id, users_jumpstart.amount, invoices.user_id, invoices.product_id, invoices.created_at as billing_date, users.username")
        ->from(['users_jumpstart' => 'Models\Jumpstart'])
        ->leftJoin('Models\Invoices', "users_jumpstart.purchaseId=invoices.id", "invoices")
        ->leftJoin('Models\Users', "invoices.user_id=users.id", "users")
        ->leftJoin('Models\CoreProducts', "invoices.product_id=products.id", "products")
        ->where('users_jumpstart.userId=:user_id:', ['user_id' => 9])
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

It returns only the columns of users_jumpstart, which are id and amount.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Everything looks perfectly fine. Two things you might want to check: 1) are there records with foreign_key = 9 in your other tables? 2) Try to dump `$builder->getPhql()` and replace models with table names and run your query directly in your SQL server to see if everything is fine.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov
I wasn't aware whether or not the data were available enough in the joined tables. Everything was correct. Spasibo for your time.